# How to write cron job in AWS EC2 server

Tags: php, cron

I've created a cron job in AWS EC2 but it is not working.

I followed below steps to create cron tab:

- Step 1: I logged in to AWS EC2 Instace
- step 2: `crontab -e`
- Step 3: Insert mode
- Step 4: I entered `* * * * * php/var/www/html/welcome.php` (To run every min.)
- Step 5: `:wq`

Cron tab is created but not running.

Please can you any one help me if is there any PHP script means please provide me. Do I need to give spaces between every star?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First of all, you need to put an space between `php` and `/var`:

From

```
* * * * * php/var/www/html/welcome.php
```

to

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/welcome.php
             ^
```

Then, you'd better use `/bin/php` instead of just `php`. To determine where the `php` executable is located, type `which php` in your console, it will give you the file path. So it will become something like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/php /var/www/html/welcome.php
          ^^^^^^^^
```

More things:

- check if crontab is saved properly? Type `crontab -l`. Your new crontab line should be there.
- is the script exactly in this dir? Try `ls -l /var/www/html/welcome.php`.
- is the script executing if you do from console? Try `/bin/php var/www/html/welcome.php` to see if it is a script or crontab problem.
- does the script have executing mode? Try `chmod 755 /var/www/html/welcome.php`

Keep us updated so we can find what can be causing the error.

Comment: I got two downvotes. May I get some hints of how to improve the answer?

Comment: Worth noting that * * * * * indicates every minute. Here is some ubuntu documentation for more help w/ timing: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: @MikeT thanks for your input, that is indeed very useful. I normally go to `man crontab` or http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info to remember how the syntax looks like.

Comment: @Yojimbo thanks for your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15474571/revisions)! I appreciate you took the time to reword it, now it is better explained ;)

Answer (score 4):

May be a too late but anyways if you intend to run the script every minute the command should probably be

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/welcome.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Running cron on EC2 is not any different from running on any *nix server - as far as I know.
I would check of the system messages for any errors. You can also redirect stderr/stdout to a file as in

```
 * * * * * <your script>  >> /var/tmp/out.log 2>&1
```

and check for any issues for starters.