# Crontab is not working in Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cron, centos

Crontab is not working on Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1. I have re-installed the crond but it is not working.

I have tried various command to install but it's not working for me:

```
yum install crond
 yum install cron
 yum install crontab
 yum install cronie
 yum install vixie-cron
```

When I checked the cron status it's showing running status.

Please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for troubleshooting in the [Stack Overflow `cron` tag info](/tags/cron/info) and [edit] your question to include the required details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write cron job in AWS EC2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470016/how-to-write-cron-job-in-aws-ec2-server)

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the link
its working properly

[How to write cron job in AWS EC2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470016/how-to-write-cron-job-in-aws-ec2-server)

## IntoTheLife

Have A Good Day

Comment: Hi, I have set the cron path as  its format in crontab, but still cron is not executing. There is no cron log on server. if cron is executing then cron log will be stored in cron-log file.

I have checked the cron services as its showing running.