# Laravel: Is it possible to run the cron job daily automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I just learned earlier how to create a cron job, now I want to execute the command daily automatically.

In my kernel file, I declared it everyMinute but when I check the path it didnt backup the file

**DbBackupDaily**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class DbBackupDaily extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'db:backupdaily';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create Database Backup Daily';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $file_name = "backup_".strtotime(now()).".sql";
        $command = "D:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.31/bin/mysqldump.exe --user=".env('DB_USERNAME')." --password=".env('DB_PASSWORD')." --host=".env('DB_HOST')." --port=".env('DB_PORT')." ".env('DB_DATABASE')." > ".storage_path()."/app/public/backup/".$file_name ;
        exec($command);

    }
}
```

**Kernel**

```
protected $commands = [
        "App\Console\Commands\DbBackupDaily",
        "App\Console\Commands\DeleteDbBackupMonthly"
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
        $schedule->command('db:backup')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('db:deletebackupmonthly')->monthly();

    }
```

Question: How do I execute the command daily automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run this command if you are in localhost:

```
php artisan schedule:work
```

Or if you are on a host, add this command to your cron jobs and set that to run every minute:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /path-to-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Hello, if our server is AWS. Where do I put this code?

Comment: So it has a different setup, you can follow these instructions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470016/how-to-write-cron-job-in-aws-ec2-server

Comment: Is there any package that I need to instal when it is in AWS server?

Comment: I don't think so, although you can search. But all you need to do is to add the command to your cron jobs. Like many tutorials that has explained.

Comment: Im getting confused, cron jobs is the file I created when i executed the commands right?

Comment: Not the file, cron jobs are basically some commands you run (e.g. every minute). For Laravel, you should run the specific command that I wrote and that command will run all your schedules in `kernel.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252716/discussion-between-angel-and-atena-dadkhah).

Comment: Hello, i followed the instructions you gave from the link and added the command. but still not working in AWS EC2 server

Answer (score 1):

You must add your schedule to a cron job.

In your panel set `path/to/php artisan schedule:run` for every minute and it will run the commands as you specified.

If you are working locally for running schedules you can use `php artisan schedule:work`